# Evaluation of the second argument to NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, evaluation, hold

The expression

```
Integrate[x^2, Flatten[{{x},{1,2}}]]
```

evaluates properly, to $\frac{7}{3}$. However,

```
NIntegrate[x^2, Flatten[{{x},{1,2}}]]
```

returns

> NIntegrate::vars: Integration range specification Flatten[{{x},{1,2}}] is not of the form {x, xmin, ..., xmax}. >>

An explicit `Evaluate` is required on the second parameter to make this work. So I assume that NIntegrate has a `HoldAll` on its second parameter.

*Did I have any way of knowing this before hand? That is, is this behavior documented? And, if it is (or even if it is not), why do the two functions behave differently?*

Comment: Such information can be found at the end of the "Details and Options" section in the documentation for `NIntegrate` (and for other functions, too).  Try also executing `Attributes[NIntegrate]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks. So do you also know why the two functions (should) behave differently? Also, if you want to post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: "…`NIntegrate` has a `HoldAll` on its second parameter…" - well, `HoldAll` does mean what it says; all inputs given are held.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that it works for [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Integrate.html) and not for [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NIntegrate.html) is that `NIntegrate` has the attribute [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldAll.html) and `Integrate` does not.  Attributes, if any, are listed at the end of the "Details and Options" section of the documentation page for a function.  They may also be inspected with the [`Attributes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Attributes.html) command:

```
Attributes@Integrate
(* {Protected,ReadProtected} *)

Attributes@NIntegrate
(* {HoldAll,Protected} *)
```

Aside from the difference point out by the OP, there is also this one if `x` has a value:

```
x = 4
(* 4 *)

NIntegrate[x^2, {x, 1, 2}]
(* 2.33333 *)

Integrate[x^2, {x, 1, 2}]
```

> Integrate::ilim: Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in {4,1,2}. >>

I do not know why the developers have chosen to treat these similar functions differently.